# What is the concept of saving session id in cookie?

Tags: java, cookies, web-applications, session-cookies

I am developing a secured website for an enterprise . I want it to be perfectly secured from all known vulnerabilities. I came across creating secure cookies and enabling HTTPOnly but in that example they were using cookie value being a sesssion Id. I didn't understand. Would not using this way can be a threat?

Comment: You're asking us? Why do you think it would be a threat?

Comment: yes I need to know the motive of sending a session id in cookie as the session id can be get from session itself.

Comment: If you don't have the session id (in a cookie for example), how do you think you can retrieve the session and the id from it? Magically?

Comment: session will be managed by tomcat server, and with request parameter I can get session?

Comment: As Thomas below said, passing the sessionid in a request param is a bad idea. Besides, if you have the sessionid in a cookie, you're not going to pass it as a parameter *too*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send a session id to the client and back to the server in order to match requests coming from that client to the session.

AFAIK there are only two ways to pass the session id: as a cookie or as a parameter (in most cases that would have be a url parameter to support get requests). Sending the session id via parameter is a vulnerability though since an attacker could provide a link with a precrafted sesssion id (session fixation) while doing the same with cookies is at least hard (if not impossible).

Sending the session id via url parameters not only is a security problem though. Assume someone copies the url and sends it to someone ("hey look at this") or posts it somewhere on the web. As long as the session exists everyone accessing that link would use the same session and iterfere with each other. Granted, there are ways to identify a user regardless of session (ip, mac address etc.) but those measures often are not feasible or impose other restrictions (how would you handle roaming mobile users for example?).

Comment: Thanks a ton for amazing explanation. Then by your saying I should create a session with session id passed by the cookie in java servlet and should use that created session id for further manipulation.

Comment: @user2695448 if you need to access the session in your application then yes you'd pass the session id in a cookie and associate each request with that session based on the cookie value - this normally should already be handled by standard web servers like Tomcat etc.. If you don't need a session, i.e. everything is read only or your application passes the entire view state/session to the client and back, then you don't need to do that.